# How to use regex for URL-targeting

Tags: regex, optimizely

As a disclaimer, I must say that my experience with regular expressions is very limited. I am using Optimizely for A/B testing and have run into a problem. I only want my experiment to run on one page, however, this page's URL-structure is somewhat complicated. The URL-structure of the page where I want to run my experiment looks like this:

```
https://mywebsite.co/term/public_id/edit/pricing
```

The problem is the `public_id` that changes dynamically, whenever a new user goes through the signup flow. How can I use regex to target this page exclusively? I have been trying to figure it out these past days but without any luck. Optimizely regex docs can be found [here](https://help.optimizely.com/Target_Your_Visitors/URL_Targeting%3A_Choose_where_your_experiment_runs#Regular_Expression_Match). I can't just use a simple match because `/term/` appears in the URL of several pages on my site.

Comment: Tried `mywebsite\.co/somepage/.*?/edit/pricing`?

Comment: A few questions to understand your question :
1.So basically the url format you will have for your test will be something like:
"https://mywebsite.co/somepage/" + public_id + "/edit/pricing" ?
What is public_id ? text or only numbers or smth else ?
2. I'm not familiar with optimizely. What do you mean by redirect ? How do you usually redirect ?

Comment: A sample `public_id` could be `bqvnd`. I never mentioned redirect.

Comment: Perfect. @trincot solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
 mywebsite\.co/somepage/.*?/edit/pricing
```

The `.*` part means any character can occur here any number of times. The additional `?` makes it lazy, meaning the rest of the regular expression will kick in as soon as possible.

Note that a literal `.` needs to be escaped with a backslash, like `\.`